# use variables to reference XML nodes in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, variables, actionscript, nodes

I have some XML nodes in AS3 which I can successfully reference using:

```
serverXML.wednesday.morning.title
```

I hace a variable called dayOfWeek that has the value "wednesday" but of course this doesn't work:

```
serverXML.dayOfWeek.morning.title
```

How can I use variables to reference XML nodes?

Comment: off the top of my head: serverXML[dayOfWeek].morning.title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using E4X notation to reference XML in AS3, you can do this to get the first match:

```
serverXML.item.(@dayOfWeek == "wednesday")[0].morning.title
```

would return the title node, assuming:

```
serverXML = <data>
<item dayOfWeek="friday"></item>
<item dayOfWeek="wednesday">
  <morning>
    <title>target</title>
  </morning>
</item>
</data>
```

if there's a chance that there is no node with the attribute match, assign it to an XMLList first to prevent errors:

```
var foo:XMLList = serverXML.item.(@dayOfWeek == "wednesday");
```

check that it has length, then reference.